# Styling multiple tables problem

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the tables on my page. The first to tables went perfect without any problems.
Now i'm trying to style the third table and I gave it a custom class but yet also seems to apply the styles from another table.

I'm using 3 rows and 6 columns.
HTML:

```
<table class="videos">
<tr>
<td>
Content
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
<--- part of another table --->
    td:nth-child(4) {
        padding-right:25px;} 
<--- part of another table --->

table.videos {
    width:940px;}

table.videos td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    padding-top:13px;}
```

So I want to style the table videos but the class td:nth-child(4) overrules somehow the td class of videos.
Using padding-right:0px; on table.videos td doesnt work...

Anyone any sugestions?
Thnx in advance!

Comment: Ooh sorry.. I really did'nt knew. I'll look in to it right now ;) 

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

styling for `td:nth-child` applies to **all** tables. you should give every table an own class, like you did for videos, and to work around this change the other css rules to be like:

```
.firsttable td:nth-child(4){
  /*something*/
}

.videos{
  /*something else*/
}

.videos td{
  /*something else*/
}
```

Comment: Oooh oke.. Great help men! Thnx alot. 
Seems so obvious.. Why have'nt I come up with this :P